# jboss 7 ignores security-domain options and requires password in encrypted form

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I use JBoss 7.1.1 and JavaEE 6. 
Passwords are stored in sql database in encrypted form, i.e.  "X8oyfUbUbfqE9IWvAW1/3"  instead of "admin". However, if I try to sign in with "admin" password, I get rejected every time  - server requires "X8oyfUbUbfqE9IWvAW1/3".

I'm using the following options in my standalone-full.xml:(I start server with -c standalone-full.xml)

`<module-option name="hashAlgorithm"     value="MD5"/>
<module-option name="hashEncoding"      value="BASE64"/>
<module-option name="hashUserPassword"  value="true"/>
<module-option name="hashStorePassword"  value="true"/>`

Comment: This may help: [How to configure JBoss DatabaseServerLoginModule for Digest Authentication in a Web Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078048/how-to-configure-jboss-databaseserverloginmodule-for-digest-authentication-in-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I finally found a solution: custom login module. It is not only short and simple, but offers a wide choice of hashing algorithms to use:

```
public class MyLoginModule extends DatabaseServerLoginModule {

   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyLoginModule.class);
   @Override
   protected boolean validatePassword(String inputPassword, String expectedPassword) {

    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    byte[] passwordBytes = inputPassword.getBytes();
    byte[] hash = md.digest(passwordBytes);
    String passwordHash =
            org.jboss.security.Base64Utils.tob64(hash);
    LOGGER.info(expectedPassword.equals(passwordHash));
    return expectedPassword.equals(passwordHash);
   }
}
```

and a snippet from my standalone.xml:

```
 <login-module code="other.MyLoginModule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/MySqlDS"/>
        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwd from USERS where login=?"/>
        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role,'Roles' from USER_ROLES where login=?"/>
 </login-module>
```